# C# regular expressions, beginning of the string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I would like to ask you a simple question about regular expressions:

How can I compare only the beginning of the string?

For example: Car [ 200 ; 200 ; 200 ], Bike [20]

```
if (item.Name == "Car*") { textBox.Text = "Car"; }
```

I don't know what I must type instead of "*" to make the rest of the string irrelevant.

Comment: For this specific use case, String.StartsWith would work fine.

Comment: You might want to add a "ToLower()" if you aren't sure about the case of your string.

Comment: Just for the sake of it, Regex uses 'line anchors' to determine the start and end of a string -> `"^Car.*"` will check that a string starts with `Car`

Comment: @drew_w There are overloads for String.StartsWith that allow specifying how case should be handled

Comment: @drew_w like @ken2k said, don't use `.ToUpper` or `.ToLower`, use `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` as the second argument, as @Habib has suggested. It's more performant and harder to mis-construe when reading code later.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see a reason to use `Regex` here. you can use [`String.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if(item.Name.StartsWith("Car")) { textBox.Text = "Car"; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of REGEX, you can do that with [`string.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if(item.Name.StartsWith("Car"))
```

If you want case insensitive comparison then you can do :

```
if(item.Name.StartsWith("car",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you still want to do with regular expression:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(item.Name, "^Car")) {
    //Something to do
}
```

or, case insensitive:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(item.Name, "^Car", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant)) {
    //Something to do
}
```

Or assign directly to the textbox:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(item.Name, "^(Car)(.*)");
if (m.Success)
    textBox.Text = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for regex.
There is nice method on String class calld StartsWith(string argument)
MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.string.startswith(v=vs.110).aspx

Use it like this:

```
string MyString = "Car [ 200 ; 200 ; 200 ], Bike [20]"
if(MyString.StartsWith("Car")) Do what you whant
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I would recommend using `String.StartsWith` as others have suggested, the regex you are looking for I believe is:

`^[cC]ar`

Assuming case insensitivity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex, then you want `(?i:^car.*)`

- `(?i:` : turns on case ignore for the rest for the rest of the group.
- `^` : matches start of string.
- `car` : looks for the string "car"
- `.*` : matches anything else, any number of characters.
- `)` : ends the group

You could also remove the group stuff and use the ignore case option on the regex object itself.

Comment: You don’t have to add the `.*`, either.

Comment: This is true. It would only be necessary if you wanted to use the captured match from the regex object.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you should use String.StartWith() function If you use regex it will mess up your code . i mean it will take more time i think.

You can go like this.

if (item.Name.startsWith("Car")) { textBox.Text = "Car"; }

Comment: @ken2k why -1 question is like that ..
sorry i don't understand your logic.
i just gave my opinion

Comment: Definition of -1 : "this answer is not useful". Not to be rude, but your answer is not useful as the exact same answer has already been provided multiple times before you did.

Comment: Ok i nknow and i can see that but this answer is usefull to the user. And the time was really less when i reply so it doesn't metter...

Comment: Sorry but it's not useful, it just adds noise to the overall thread. Plus, you answered 7 minutes later top answers.

Comment: @Nitesh Kumar SHARMA - +1 for the usefull answer. I often post on SO first, refresh the page and have the only answer on it, just to be shocked 5 minutes later to see some other poster has posted 3 minutes before me and 2 minutes before the question was posted, only to be merged to the same time after 1 hour. I can't imagine this post is anything but helpfull, it certainly isin't wrong. Welcome to SO!